# Can not share a pretyped text with ACTION_SEND to socials

Tags: facebook, android-intent, text, hyperlink, share

I am trying to use a ACTION_SEND intent for sharing my aplication throug anything that can post text which i select.

i use this code

```
public void sharebutton(View v){
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<p>Try this android application https://link...</p>"));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share by"));
    }
```

For example i want to select Facebook and it should load up facebook app and in the text field there should be: "Try this android application https://link..."
but instead it either doesnt show me the option for sharing via facebook if i use `sharingIntent.setType("text/html");`(it does show emails, dropbox and blootooth) or it doesn't place the text inside if i use `sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");`

Have a solution for me? Feel free to help.

Comment: You are __not allowed__ to pre-fill the message part of any share, see [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy#control). The message has to be a 100% user generated, i.e. typed in by the user himself.

Comment: Oh and can i somehow share my application in different way?

Comment: You can let users share a link … but you must allow them to type the message themselves.

Comment: And the link can be pretyped?

Comment: Okay lets say it's impossible for facebook. what about other sites..

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#share_dialog

Answer (score 0):

you should integrate the facebook SDK and use it to share a pretyped text on Facebook, but in twitter it will work just by using ACTION_SEND ... and put_extra